# Does the Encog framework add extra neurons automatically?

Tags: neural-network

I recently started using Encog and used

```
 BasicNetwork network = new BasicNetwork();
 network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationSigmoid(), true, 1));
 network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationSigmoid(), true, 2));
 network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationSigmoid(), true, r.Length));
 network.Structure.FinalizeStructure();
 network.Reset();
```

to declare a network with 1 input , 2 hidden and 3 outputs, I need to know the amount of space ram required for the all the weights, usually it would be
((1*2)+2+(2*3))*((2^64)-1)/4 but this network seems to be able to fit any amount of data 100% accurately, suspicious. So I was wondering if maybe it adds more neurons if it can't train properly, does it do this? Any help appreciated.